# simply regex date validation

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I'm trying to create simply regex validation for my mvc application. I tried:

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression("(\\d\\d\\/\\d\\d\\/\\d\\d\\d\\d)")]
```

and it is not working. I want to force customer to enter date in format 01/01/2015

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why you need regex for this case? Use `DisplayFormat` and `DataType`:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

I mean it just wrong to validate a date with regex. There is no easy way to validate dates like `31/02/2015` or `31/04/2015` which is not a valid date.

Comment: but i've  issue  in this case I'm not able to add date more than 12

Comment: @UddyanSemwal you've got the issue somewhere in localization, it's a bit tricky probably you should make it right on the client side, I believe you should ask another question with all add to reproduce the issue and someone will help you.

Comment: it has been solved as db requires yyyy-MM-dd format I've changes it works man @teovankot

Answer (score 2):

It might be due to the confusion caused by escaping so many characters.

Here I have escaped the whole string by prepending `@` and condensed the regex by using quantifiers to specify how many characters of each digit class to capture:

```
[RegularExpression(@"(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})")]
```

However, since you're using this to validate date entries you might want to consider using a DateTime validator as [teo van kot has mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34059089/623487) because this regex doesn't enforce valid date values.

Comment: thank you for your help, I think I've made mistake somewhere else. I'm aware of limitations of my reg ex but it should work.